# How do I beat Oogie Boogie in the Torture Chamber?

Tags: kingdom-hearts

I have died three times now, because I have no idea how I am supposed to beat this boss. I keep getting hit by all the things he throws on to the roulette wheel type thing, and I can never seem to get near him. How do I beat this boss?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every once and a while, Oogie will throw dice at you. Simply use attack to hit these dice back in his direction and it will do damage to him. After a few hits, you'll get the chance to hop up and hit him with your keyblade. Buttons in the middle of the arena will glow, and when you hit one, you can trap both you and him into a wedge. The floor will rise and you'll get your chance. Wail on him, rinse, repeat.

After you beat him...

> Oogie will become the building. When this happens, the way to beat him is to destroy the purple orbs that are located all over his body. Simply climb up the building and destroy these to win.

Comment: Okay, that sounds a little confusing, but I shall try it out and see how it goes!